# jQueryUI datepicker: Month/Year Menus with Localization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'd like to do a **jQuery UI datepicker** widget that has both month/year menu as seen at [datepicker: jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year), but it also needs to be localized, as seen at [datepicker jQuery UI:localization](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization).

I'm not sure if both can be done together. I have not been able to get it to work. If I add the localization code, I do see the calendar localized properly, but I lose the month/year menus.

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charliegriefer/5LXey/) for a working sample of the i18n. if you comment out the i18n line:

```
$( "#dob" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ar" ] );
```

... then you'll see the month/year menus work properly.

Does anybody know of a way to get these both working together in a single widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to understand is that the first time you call the `datepicker` function whatever you pass to it will be used to initialize the widget.  After that, each additional call to `datepicker` will be used to call methods or set options.

In your jsfiddle, try:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }).datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional[ "ar" ]);
});​
```

In this manner we are initializing the datepicker with the options for `changeMonth` and `changeYear`.  On our next call we can update an option, making it regional.

Comment: Thank you! I tried combining the two references but obviously was not able to come up with this syntax. Looks like it works a treat.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation as well. had to read it a couple of times, but it did make sense :)

Comment: No problem.  jQuery is bizarre syntax at first by itself -- and jQuery UI adds more complexity with their widgets.  But once you understand them they are fantastic to work with.  If you really want to understand how they work (so you can author your own), read up on the [jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory).  This documentation is a little outdated since they are now on UI 1.9, but it is the best explanation out there.