# jqueryUI datePicker constructor

Tags: jquery-ui

Can someone explain me how to create a jquery UI datepicker with both properties `changeMonth` **and** localization?

I have these two lines of code:

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en']);
$('.datePicker').datepicker({ changeMonth: true });
```

I'd like to merge them into a single line, since the second one seems to fail if not called when and only when constructing the datepicker for the first time. Unfortunately, I can't do this since I don't know to which property assign the `$.datepicker.regional['en']`.

Thanks.

I've already tried this, with no success: [jQueryUI datepicker: Month/Year Menus with Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000128/jqueryui-datepicker-month-year-menus-with-localization?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = $.extend($.datepicker.regional['en'], { changeMonth: true, other settings... })
$('.datePicker').datepicker(obj);
```

Using jquery [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), we can combine both the settings object and the localizator object.

Answer (score -1):

You can set any number of properties after you initialize the datapicker as follows:-

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "both",
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
buttonText: "Calendar"
});
```